# что нужно этой @app.on_message?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, pyrogram

пишу приложение на kivy и захотел к нему пришить проект ЮзерБот сделал все норм, по моему должно было все работать а тут БАЦ @app.on_message начинает ругаться помогите пожалуйста( да я рукожоп - новичек, если не сложно обьясните что это такое @app.on_message читал статью ничего не понел)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window


from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait

from pyrogram.types import ChatPermissions



Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)    # установка цвета нового фона
#Config.set("graphics", "relizeble", "0")# ---\
#Config.set("graphics", "width", "400")   #    \ высота и ширина экрана, изменять его потом нельзя
#Config.set("graphics", "heigth", "600")#------/

class MyApp(App):

        def build(self):

            fl = AnchorLayout()
            bl = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical", size_hint = (.5, .5))
            self.text_input = TextInput(text = "api_id", font_size=25, background_color=[1, 1, 1, 1])
            self.text_input1 = TextInput(text = "api_hash", font_size=25)
            bl.add_widget(self.text_input)  # позиция
            bl.add_widget(self.text_input1)


            bl.add_widget(Button(
                text = "подтвердить",
                font_size=25,  # font_size рaзмер шрифта
                on_press=self.btn_press,  # on_press нажата
                background_color=[1, 1, 1, 1]  # background_color цвет RGBA в %
               # background_normal="", # background_normal  делает цвет ярче
            ))# позиция



            fl.add_widget(bl)
            #s = Scatter()
            #s.add_widget(fl)
            return fl


        def btn_press(self, instance):
            print(self.text_input.text)
            print(self.text_input1.text)
            app = Client("00ef8b3beaab981d8661a5e596123447", api_id= self.text_input.text, api_hash=self.text_input1.text)

@app.on_message(filters.text & filters.private)
def echo(client, message):
    message.reply_text(message.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: У вас не существует глобальной переменной `app`. Вы создаёте локальную переменную `app` внутри функции `btn_press`, но даже если эту функцию и запустить, переменная `app` будет уничтожена мгновенно после завершения работы функции, потому что переменная — локальная и существует только во время работы этой функции.

Comment: как я могу это исправить?

Comment: у меня вкоде получается при нажатии кнопки срабатывает функция btn_press и получает данные из Textinput и эти данные указываю в переменные api_id и api_hash которые нужны САМОЙ ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ арр или есть более выгодный способ?

Comment: Зачем вы вообще создаёте app внутри функции? Просто уберите все пробелы перед app — и она станет глобальной переменной и возможно всё заработает (ну или появится какая-нибудь другая ошибка)